# Final and top-level lazy initialization

Tags: dart

**Please help me to understand what it exactly means:**

Quote from the ["Chapter 2. A Tour of the Dart Language"](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#final-and-const)

> A local, top-level, or class variable that’s declared as final is initialized the first time it’s used

So this is my test code:

```dart
lazyTest(msg) => print(msg);

class Printer{
  Printer(msg){
    print(msg);
  }
  final finalClassVariable = lazyTest("final class variable");
}

var globalsAreLazy = lazyTest("top-level");
var lazyInitialized = lazyTest("lazy initialized");

void main() {

   final localFinal = new Printer("local final");
   var initialize = lazyInitialized;
}
```

Output:

> final class variable
>   local final
>   lazy initialized

Both `finalClassVariable` and `localFinal`  initialized and only `globalsAreLazy` wasn't. `lazyInitialized` was initialized on access as i expected.

Comment: The quoted text has now been changed to not mention local variables.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Class variables is another name for static fields, so you need to make `finalClassVariable` static for it to be lazy.

The text is incorrect on local variables. They are initialized when the declaration is executed, not lazily when it is first read.

Non-static class fields with initializer expressions are initialized when a constructor is called. They are not lazy.

Answer (score 5):

`finalClassVariable` is an instance variable not a class variable. To make it a class variable you have to prepend `static`.

Comment: Got it. But why local variable "localFinal" was initialized?